# Convert formatted Javascript time/date to Universal Time Stamp

Tags: javascript

I need my date and time to be converted into UTC/universal time stamp and I'm not sure how to convert it (I am working in EST). I need it in this format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss which I have built already using this snippet of code:

```
var now = new Date();
var year = "" + now.getFullYear();
var month = "" + (now.getMonth() + 1); 

if (month.length == 1) {
    month = "0" + month; 
}
day = "" + now.getDate(); 
if (day.length == 1) { 
    day = "0" + day; 
}
hour = "" + now.getHours(); 
if (hour.length == 1) { 
    hour = "0" + hour; 
}
minute = "" + now.getMinutes();
if (minute.length == 1) { 
    minute = "0" + minute; 
}
second = "" + now.getSeconds(); 
if (second.length == 1) { 
    second = "0" + second; 
}
var timeStamp = year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;
```

This returns something like "2017-05-19 16:23:19" How would we convert it to UTC, if possible? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not usually one to recommend libraries on here and I'll only do it in a comment (not an answer) but to avoid the agonizing pain of this, you could look into [`moment.js`](http://momentjs.com/). Let it handle the formatting for you and save yourself a lot of time and `if` statements...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code 
First create a javascript date object , here is the call

```
new Date(year, month[, date[, hours[, minutes[, seconds[, milliseconds]]]]]);
```

Then

```
var isoDate = new Date('yourdatehere').toISOString();
```

So for you it will be

```
var date = new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, 0);
var isoDate = date.toISOString();
```

in fiddle I tried to do it. Maybe this is how you want it

https://jsfiddle.net/pvu6ctsd/

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do it:

```js
var timestamp = "2017-05-19 16:23:19"; //substitute by your timestamp variable
var date = new Date(timestamp.replace(' ', 'T') + 'Z');
var strUDate = date.toISOString();
console.log(strUDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create a date in Javascript `new Date()` your object stores how many minutes before or after UTC it was created. You can see this anytime using the `getTimezoneOffset()` method

If you want the UTC time as a string, there is only one method you can use.

```
const date = new Date();
date.toUTCString();
// Fri, 19 May 2017 21:07:27 GMT
```

If you want it in your preferred string format you will have to build the string manually in a similar way to as you did. Just replace your methods with UTC methods.

```
const date = new Date();

const year = "" + date.getUTCDate();
let month = "" + (date.getUTCMonth() + 1); // we add a 1 because month is 0 based
if (month.length == 1) {
  month = "0" + month; 
}
let day = "" + date.getUTCDate(); 
if (day.length == 1) { 
  day = "0" + day; 
}
let hour = "" + date.getUTCHours(); 
if (hour.length == 1) { 
  hour = "0" + hour; 
}
let minute = "" + date.getUTCMinutes();
if (minute.length == 1) { 
  minute = "0" + minute; 
}
let second = "" + date.getUTCSeconds(); 
if (second.length == 1) { 
  second = "0" + second; 

const timeStamp = year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hour + ":" +  minute + ":" + second;
```

And if you want short hand

```
const d = new Date();
const dateString = `${d.getUTCFullYear()}-${('0' + d.getUTCMonth()).slice(-2)}-${('0' + d.getUTCDate()).slice(-2)} ${('0' + d.getUTCHours()).slice(-2)}:${('0' + d.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2)}:${('0' + d.getUTCSeconds()).slice(-2)}`;
// 2017-04-19 23:39:28
```